# How to replace all the text content on a web page in WKWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a browser app which is basically WKWebView and I want to add a translation feature similar to chrome and safari browsers, which allows you to translate all the text content on web page.

I am not too familiar with javascript. So the idea is to just iterate through web page content using JavaScript and get all the texts, then pass it to Swift, do the translation natively, and then pass back the translated texts to WKWebView and replace the texts to the translated ones.

Is this the right approach and if so could you please hint to how it can be done on JavaScript part? Or is there a better solution, or is there a solution at all?

Comment: Providing localized content is obviously the ideal approach. Translation introduces many complicating factors. One of the harder parts is categorizing the "texts": how do you determine which strings belong together and which should be separated? A common approach is to build your site/app's views from structured textual data that you can replace with another language during render.

Comment: @jsejcksn the task is to do it on any web page, so I have no prior access to the content to localize it. It's need to be done at runtime